# IndexOutOfBoundsException in Edit Text for android

Tags: android

i have an edit text in my activity.i am entering numbers in it manually but

```
   int mystart = destinationNumber.getSelectionStart();
   int myend = destinationNumber.getSelectionEnd();
   numberText.getText().replace(Math.min(mystart, myend), Math.max(mystart, myend),
                        "1", 0, 1);
```

its entering fine according to the cursor position.

i have a delete button in my acitivity which deletes single character according to cursor postion.

```
numberText.getText().delete(myend - 1, mystart);
```

But this logic is not working properly when i select whole text and call delete method it gives me IndexOutOfBoundsException OR i select 4-5 digits and call this delete.

I want the same functionality as android contact dialpad number enter field.Can someone help me figure out what is the correct logic to delete single digit from edittext and multiple selected digits as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`delete`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html#delete%28int,%20int%29) receives the start as first parameter and end as second, not the other way around.

Comment: but  when i only use `numberText.getText().delete(myend, mystart);`      it does not delete single character when i call this method.i have to say "myend - 1" to delete 1 character.

Comment: But this code fails when you select first 2-3 digits from edit text and call this method.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error its taht mystart or myend(probably this) are bigger or smoller than numberText.lenght().

Try to put a Log.d("","" ) with the lenght of the text, mystart and myend and check if you need a myend -1 or something like that.